# So that I can vs So that I may

Tags: backshifting, can-may

In the cases below, do I always have to use 'may' instead of 'can'?
Both sound correct to me however, I had read explanations that said that 'may' should be used after 'so that'.

I came earlier so that I **may** help them.
I came earlier so that I **can** help them.

Please be on time so that we **may** leave before 5.
Please be on time so that we **can** leave before 5.

Thanks

Comment: In the past tense you'll need to use *could* not *can*, *might* not *may*.

Answer (score 2):

The OP says, *"I had read explanations that said that 'may' should be used after 'so that'".* I don't think there is such a hard and fast grammar rule.

**Can** and **may** can be used to express *possibility* and *permission* with some differences.

> **Possibility**: (from ***[English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/can-could-or-may)***, Cambridge Dictionary)
>
> When we talk about possibility, we use **can**, **could** and **may**,
> but they are different in meaning.
>
> *Compare:*
>
> *It can be dangerous to cycle in the city.* (This expresses what the speaker believes is a general truth or known fact, or a strong
> possibility.)
>
> *It could/may be dangerous to cycle in the city.* (This does not express a general truth. The speaker is only expressing a weak
> possibility.)
>
> **Permission**:
>
> We use **can, could** and **may** to ask for permission. We use
> ***can*** and ***may***, but **not could**, to give permission. **May** is less common:
>
> *Compare:*
>
> *Can I ask you a question?* ( ***informal*** )
>
> *Could I use your phone?* (***more formal/polite***)
>
> *May I use your phone?* (***even more formal/polite***)

Also from ***[Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823030009/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/can-or-may)***:

> ### ‘Can’ or ‘may’?
>
> People are often uncertain about whether there is any difference
> between can and may when these verbs are used to ask for or grant
> permission. For example, is one of these two sentences ‘more correct’
> than the other?
>
> Can I ask you a few questions?
>
> May I ask you a few questions?
>
> There is a widespread view that using can to ask for permission is
> wrong and that it should only be used in expressions to do with
> ability or capability, e.g.:
>
> Can she swim?
>
> Can you speak Italian?
>
> But the 'permission' use of *can* is not in fact incorrect in standard
> English. The only difference between the two verbs is that one is more
> polite than the other. In *informal* contexts it’s perfectly
> acceptable to use *can*; in *formal* situations it would be better to
> use *may*.

Answer (score 0):

**Can** means you're able to do something.

**May** means you're permitted to do something.

Comment: I'd like to know in this exact context if both are permitted.

Comment: In informal usage, either will work.  _May_ tends to sound a little more formal, but it's not, really.  In your second example, you could get away with either, but _can_ is the better choice -- _Please be on time so that we **are able to** leave before 5._ versus _Please be on time so that we **will be allowed** to leave before 5._

Comment: Your first example, however, is not a good one -- the tenses don't match.  I should be _I came earlier so that I **might** help them._ or _I came earlier so that I **could** help them._  Alternatively, you could say _I will **come** earlier so that I may/can help them._  Unless you're going to be punished by not being allowed to help if you don't show up early, you probably still want _can_.